# Log file missed when running jmeter 5.4.1

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a problem running jmeter on a debian 9 machine . i downloaded the latest version on the /usr/share file and added all the required env variables with java 8 version  in order to run my Tests . but every jmeter command i run i get this error :
[image]

I should precise that the jmeter.log file doesn't exist in my bin repository .
Did i miss something . any body knows how to solve this please

Thank you .

Comment: I verified .. all jars related to log4j are installed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "the latest version on the /usr/share file" means, your issue cannot be reproduced on Debian stretch so I would recommend starting "clean"

1. [Update packages cache](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

   ```
   apt-get update
   ```
2. Install Java 8 and wget (for downloading JMeter)

   ```
   apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y openjdk-8-jre wget
   ```
3. Download [latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) to i.e. `/opt` folder and unpack it:

   ```
   cd /opt && wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.1.tgz && tar xf apache-jmeter-5.4.1.tgz
   ```
4. Go to JMeter's "bin" folder:

   ```
   cd /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/
   ```
5. Run example test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui):

   ```
   ./jmeter -n -t ../extras/Test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
6. You should see *jmeter.log* file in the current folder without any errors in it

More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

Comment: Dmitri T , i tried this and i have the same issue